# PHP url routing regex

Tags: php, regex

I am using a regular expression to route my application, this is the regex I am using:

```
@/users/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/posts@
```

But unfortunately it matches against these these urls too:

```
/users/:uid/posts/:pid
/users/:uid/posts/:pid/comment/:cid
```

But it shouldn't, it should match exact the same url so only:

```
/users/:uid/posts
```

What should I change in the regex to make it match the exact same string?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include [anchors](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.anchors.php) for the beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string:

```
@^/users/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/posts/?$@
```

I also allowed for an optional `/` at the end of the URL.